# HTML form with php adding "?" in the url instead of do the php script

Tags: php, html, forms

I'm working in a *contact section* in a website and ***I need to send all the contact form's to a mail***.

The problem is, I have a php script who make all the job, but; **when I click "send"**, the site **refresh** and the *url changes* from "www.site.com/contact.html" to "www.site.com/contact.html?".

By the way, I'm working with Bootstrap and PHP 5.

I think the problem is the form is don't recognize the script or I don't linked the script with the form correctly. I tried to use the `action="form_contact.php` property in the html form tag.

**HTML**

```html
<div class="row justify-content-center" style=" width: 100%">
            <div class="col-10 col-md-6 justify-content-center align-self-center">
                <form id="form_46788" data-form-type="blocs-form" novalidate data-success-msg="Your message was sent succsessfuly" data-fail-msg="Ups! something go wrong, try again.">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>
                            Name
                        </label>
                        <input id="name_46788" class="form-control" required data-validation-required-message="Send your name" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>
                            Email
                        </label>
                        <input id="email_46788" class="form-control" type="email" required data-validation-required-message="Invalid Email" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>
                            Tell us about you<br>
                        </label><textarea id="message_46788" class="form-control" rows="4" cols="50" required data-validation-required-message="Invalid Message"></textarea>
                    </div> 
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">
                        Send
                    </button>
                </form>
            </div>  
        </div>
```

**PHP (file name: form_contact.php)**

```
<?php   
    if(empty($_POST['name_contact']) && strlen($_POST['name_contact']) == 0 || empty($_POST['email_contact']) && strlen($_POST['email_contact']) == 0 || empty($_POST['message_contact']) && strlen($_POST['message_contact']) == 0)
    {
        return false;
    }

    $name_contact = $_POST['name_contact'];
    $email_contact = $_POST['email_contact'];
    $message_contact = $_POST['message_contact'];

    $to = 'irivero@ngine.digital'; // Email submissions are sent to this email

    // Create email 
    $email_subject = "Mensaje desde el website";
    $email_body = "Haz recibido un mensaje desde la página web \n\n".
                  "Name_contact: $name_contact \nEmail_contact: $email_contact \nMessage_contact: $message_contact \n";
    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\nContent-type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\r\n";  
    $headers .= "From: web@site.com\n";
    $headers .= "Reply-To: $email_contact"; 

    mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers); // Post message
    return true;            
?>
```

The actual result I need to get is:

If some field don't have any information, the `data-validation` in the form inputs need to show the `data-validation-required-message="error"` message.

If all the fields are correct, the script will work and I will recieve the contact form in my mail.

Comment: `<input>` 's need  a `name` attribute for PHP to see the data. yours only have `id` attributes

Comment: The form is defaulting to a get you need to add method="post" to your form.

Comment: You WILL need to use the `action="form_contact.php` in the `<form>` tag as well

Comment: I added the `action="form_contact.php"` in `<form>` and added the `name` attribute in all the `<inputs>` and `<textarea>`, but still not working, now the url goes to `site.com/includes/form_contact.php?name_contact=&email_contact=&message_contact=` insted of don't go to any site because the form don't have any field complete.

Comment: Did you also add the `method="post"` to your form tag also as @JasonK mentioned?

Comment: @Dave Yes, It worked, the only thing I don't understand is why when I click "send" and the text fields are empty, the validation get ignored and the website redirect to `site.com/includes/form_contact.php` (by the way, if all the fields have info, the form become send correctly)

Comment: It is due to the way you are checking for fields not being completed. The mixture of  `and`s and `or`s is not working the way you think it is. `empty` includes checking for an empty value so the additional `strlen` tests shouldn't be necessary. Simply `empty($_POST['field1']) OR empty($_POST['field2'])` etc.

Comment: See my answer. Hope this helps.

Comment: I tested the code of my answer and works fine...

Comment: [UpVote](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qq7YZ.png) [Mark Answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oB3cT.png) as you can see you can vote and mark answer according to the pictures..

Comment: Did you solve your issue?

Comment: Yes @Alessandro , The problem was in the person who gave me the code, he did not attach the Java Script code that correctly connects the HTML with the PHP

Answer (score 1):

Ok, your code presents some errors, I edited your code to get it working, I added some extra validations through php (better than html5), now should works fine, I have not tested all code, let me know if it's enough for you...

`form.php`

```
<?php @ini_set('default_charset', 'UTF-8'); ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta name="pragma" content="no-cache">
  <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">
  <title>Contact Form</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="form.css">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico">
</head>

<body>

<div class="row justify-content-center" style="width: 100%">
  <div class="col-10 col-md-6 justify-content-center align-self-center">
    <p class="error"><?php if (isset($error)) { echo $error; } ?></p>
    <form name="form" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], NULL, 'UTF-8'); ?>" method="post">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Name</label>
        <input name="name_contact" id="name_contact" placeholder="Your Name..." value="<?php if (isset($_POST['name_contact'])) { echo htmlentities($_POST['name_contact'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); } ?>">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Email</label>
        <input name="email_contact" id="email_contact" placeholder="Your Email Address..." value="<?php if (isset($_POST['email_contact'])) { echo htmlentities($_POST['email_contact'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); } ?>">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Tell us about you</label><br />
        <textarea name="message_contact" id="message_contact" class="form-control" rows="4" cols="50" placeholder="Your Message..."><?php if (isset($_POST['message_contact'])) { echo htmlentities($_POST['message_contact'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); } ?></textarea>
      </div> 
      <button class="btn btn-primary" name="submit" type="submit">Send</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

`contact.php`

```
<?php
@ini_set('default_charset', 'UTF-8');
if (!isset($_POST['name_contact']) || !isset($_POST['email_contact']) || !isset($_POST['message_contact'])) {
  $error = "Please, fill all required fields!";
  include("./form.php");
  exit();
}
if (!isset($_POST['name_contact']) || empty($_POST['name_contact']) || strlen($_POST['name_contact']) == 0) {
  $error = "Please, provide a valid email name!";
  include("./form.php");
  exit();
} else {
  $name_contact = htmlentities($_POST['name_contact'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
}
if (!isset($_POST['email_contact']) || empty($_POST['email_contact']) || strlen($_POST['email_contact']) == 0 || !preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+([_\\.-][a-zA-Z0-9]+)*". "@([a-zA-Z0-9]+([\.-][a-zA-Z0-9]+))+$/", $_POST['email_contact'])) {
  $error = "Please, provide a valid email address!";
  include("./form.php");
  exit();
} else {
  $email_contact = $_POST['email_contact'];
}
if (!isset($_POST['message_contact']) || empty($_POST['message_contact']) || strlen($_POST['message_contact']) == 0) {
  $error = "Please, provide a valid email message!";
  include("./form.php");
  exit();
} else {
  $message_contact = htmlentities($_POST['message_contact'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
}
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  $to = 'irivero@ngine.digital'; // Email submissions are sent to this email
  // Create email 
  $email_subject = "Mensaje desde el website";
  $email_body = "Haz recibido un mensaje desde la página web\n\n" . "Name_contact: $name_contact\nEmail_contact: $email_contact\nMessage_contact: $message_contact\n";
  $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\nContent-type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\r\n";
  $headers .= "From: web@site.com\n";
  $headers .= "Reply-To: $email_contact"; 
  if (mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers)) { // Post message
    $error = "SUCCESS: Your Message is Sent!";
    include("./form.php");
    exit();
  } else {
    $error = "WARNING: Your Message cannot be Sent!";
    include("./form.php");
    exit();
  }
}
?>
```

Just load `contact.php` to get the html form working... I hope this helps.